# Combining where condition in C# linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Take this example

```
var eventid = 2997;
var event = _db.Events.Where(q => q.EventId == eventid && q.SomeBoolField == false).ToList();
```

Let us assume that event id is repeated in many rows of the table, i.e. it is not a primary key. Let us also assume the table has millions of records. Is it advised to split the 2 where clauses into separate? Like so:

```
var event = _db.Events.Where(q => q.EventId == eventid).Where(q.SomeBoolField == false).ToList();
```

My thinking is, is that the second example will get a smaller subset of the data first, before looking at SomeBoolField.

What is the recommended practice?

Comment: I assume you're talking about Entity Framework.  EF deals with expression trees and it combines the expressions in the second `Where` call, so it doesn't matter which way you do it, you'll get your first version in the end.

Comment: Either is fine. I'd lean towards the former, but the difference is marginal at best.

Comment: As for getting *"a smaller subset of the data first"*, it's the responsibility of good indexing to enable the query engine to do that.

Comment: In addition to all of the above, the first `Where()` bool condition is short-circuiting, so you would not see any benefit.

Comment: @TK That doesn't matter when using LINQ to EF/SQL as it is up to SQL to handle it.

Comment: Either way LINQ to EF/SQL will translate the expression tree to SQL and it will be up to the database engine to run the query, so micro-optimization of the LINQ that executes server-side is fruitless.